# XAML graphic vector as image source

Tags: wpf, xaml

Now many graphics designers provide the images as xaml file not ico, png, ..., How can I use a xaml file as image source?

Thanks

Comment: can you show an example of xaml file not ico, png. maybe photo or printscreen

Answer (score 0):

From [the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751619(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
<Image>
  <Image.Source>
    <DrawingImage PresentationOptions:Freeze="True">
      <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing>
          <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            <GeometryGroup>
              <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50" RadiusX="45" RadiusY="20" />
              <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="45" />
            </GeometryGroup>
          </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
          <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
              <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Blue" />
              <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#CCCCFF" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
          </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
          <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
            <Pen Thickness="10" Brush="Black" />
          </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
        </GeometryDrawing>
      </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage>
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Instead of in-lining the GeometryDrawing you could refer to it as a static resource that you keep in a Resourcedictionary.

```
<Image>
  <Image.Source>
    <DrawingImage PresentationOptions:Freeze="True" 
                  Drawing="{StaticResource myDrawing}">
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

You will also find that you can show the drawing only once this way. So if you want this image to be present in the UI in multiple places, put the Image in a control template and style the controls with the template.

Comment: Thanks too all, this approach I know, my question was what happens when I have 100 xaml graphics files provided by a designer, now I have to extract the content from each file to move in a resource dictionary and set a key for each. I ask only if a more easy way as time.

Comment: @ToaderIoan - you should have mentioned that in the question. All depends on how you want to store the drawings. You could write a simple powershell script that reads all xaml files in a dictionary and merges them into one big resource dictionary file with each image keyed with the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks too all, this approach I know, my question was what happens when I have 100 xaml graphics files provided by a designer, now I have to extract the content from each file to move in a resource dictionary and set a key for each. I ask only if a more easy way as time.

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank again too all.

I got a graphic like this

```html
<Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Width="128" Height="128">
  <Canvas Width="10240" Height="10240">
  <Path Data="M5986 6814l828 -828c124,-124 328,-124 452,0l2428 2428c124,124 124,328 0,452l-828 828c-124,124 -328,124 -452,0l-2428 -2428c-124,-124 -124,-328 0,-452z" Fill="#EDC87E"/>
  <Path Data="M6082 5442l412 412 -640 640 -412 -412c-534,401 -1197,638 -1916,638 -1764,0 -3194,-1430 -3194,-3194 0,-1764 1430,-3194 3194,-3194 1764,0 3194,1430 3194,3194 0,719 -237,1382 -638,1916zm-2556 -4471c-1411,0 -2555,1144 -2555,2555 0,1411 1144,2555 2555,2555 1411,0 2555,-1144 2555,-2555 0,-1411 -1144,-2555 -2555,-2555z" Fill="#808080"/>
  </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

This can be user very easy as a content to a Content control, but to youse this for a control which requires Image source I cannot I have to transform to:

```
 <DrawingImage>
            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <DrawingGroup.Children>
                        <GeometryDrawing  Geometry="M5986 6814l828 -828c124,-124 328,-124 452,0l2428 2428c124,124 124,328 0,452l-828 828c-124,124 -328,124 -452,0l-2428 -2428c-124,-124 -124,-328 0,-452z" Brush="#EDC87E">
                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                <Pen Thickness="1000" Brush="Blue"></Pen>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing  Geometry="M6082 5442l412 412 -640 640 -412 -412c-534,401 -1197,638 -1916,638 -1764,0 -3194,-1430 -3194,-3194 0,-1764 1430,-3194 3194,-3194 1764,0 3194,1430 3194,3194 0,719 -237,1382 -638,1916zm-2556 -4471c-1411,0 -2555,1144 -2555,2555 0,1411 1144,2555 2555,2555 1411,0 2555,-1144 2555,-2555 0,-1411 -1144,-2555 -2555,-2555z" Brush="#808080"/>
                    </DrawingGroup.Children>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
        </DrawingImage>
```

The work in to trivial :(